# Static Menu on all Subpages

Tags: php, html

I am creating a HTML/PHP based Website. Now I would like to add a menu but that menu should have on all pages the same structure like on a CMSso I mean:

On a normal/static dynamic website with subdirectories you have following structure

```
<nav>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="solution/">Solution</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

but if it a php file is on a subdirctoryas solution

```
<nav>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="">Solution</a></li>
      <li><a href="../about.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="../contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

On a normal CMS you see on all page also on pages witch are in 'subdirectories'

```
<nav>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="/solution/">Solution</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I think with you can easy manage and change that kind of menu and you donnt have to change a mistake on 50 pages:)

I think I could do it with PHP but dont have any idea.

Maybe with Base URL but the the url would look like

```
 <li><a href="https://example.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
```

and thats not that what I mean and want to get.

Hope you could give me an advice how to realize that

Comment: Just create your menu in a seperate file and include it through php in the place you want it.

Comment: @ChrisG that was easy and how to add the CSS and JS to all pages so a website/file or menu looks just like the other pages even if it is in the subdirectories

Comment: @ChrisG but if you use  include it through the you will get not about.php, you get soution/about.php

Comment: <?php 
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/soution/menu.php";
   include_once($path);
?>

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the CMS of your choice. For Wordpress for example to establish base reference you use something like `<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/sample.php">Your Page</a>`. If you later decide that sample page need to be called page-new for example I would go with find and replace function of any good editor out there. It will take certainly time for 50 or more links but it will be significantly less.